# Excel VBA for Mac: ComboBox Workaround

Tags: excel, macos, vba, combobox

I am unable to populate my ComboBox on a UserForm on a Mac.

I have created a dynamic named range called "nameList", whose formula looks as such:

```
"=OFFSET('MEMBERS LIST'!$D$4,0,0,COUNTA('MEMBERS LIST'!$D:$D)-1)"
```

On Sheet1 (named: HOME), I have created a Macro which calls up a UserForm (named: PostForm), where I have created a ComboBox (named: username_Insert). On Windows, I simply have to go to the Properties box & type "nameList" in the RowSource property. This populates the ComboBox with my dynamic nameList. However, when I attempt to read my Worksheet on a Mac, the list turns up empty.

I have tried multiple solutions within code:

```
Private Sub PostForm_Initialize()
    'Populate Username combo box.
    'Me.username_Insert.List = [nameList]
    'Me.username_Insert.List = Range("nameList")
    'Me.username_Insert.List = Range([nameList])

    'Me.username_Insert.AddItem = [nameList]
End Sub
```

I'm unsure if I'm entering the code in the correct sub or if I should be entering my code within the following sub: Private Sub username_Insert_Change()

/*******RESOLVED*******/

Modified the code to take in the other dynamic lists I had, resulted in the following code. Implemented into the UserForm Code, worked like a charm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim nme As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Members List")
    For Each nme In ws.Range("nameList")
        Me.username_Insert.AddItem nme.Value
    Next nme

    Set ws = Sheets("SONY DATA")
    For Each nme In ws.Range("phoneList")
        Me.phone_Insert.AddItem nme.Value
    Next nme

    For Each nme In ws.Range("ampm")
        Me.daynight_Insert.AddItem nme.Value
    Next nme

    For Each nme In ws.Range("typeList")
        Me.type_Insert.AddItem nme.Value
    Next nme

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to populate your combobox item-by-item.
Given that it is a dynamic list I suggest that you put the code in the Userform's Activate event.
Note that this event is found (and the code should be placed) in the Userform's code module NOT in a general code module.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim nme As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Members List")
    For Each nme In ws.Range("nameList")
        Me.username_Insert.AddItem nme.Value
    Next nme

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Adding items line-by-line *works*, but it can be done more straightforwardly (and elegantly) by simply populating the LIST property of the Combobox with all the values in one line of code as follows :

```
Private Sub Userform_Activate()
    username_Insert.List = Sheets("Members List").Range("nameList").value
End sub
```

You were very close in your original attempts, you just needed to add .value to the

=Range("nameList")

line.  :-)